# throwing exception from constructor

Tags: c++

Out of my curiosity..

I notice when I throw exceptions from constructor, if I compiled the code in debug mode and if I click on continue debugging (or continue stepping through), it won't exit the constructor until it reaches the end. Please note I don't have try{}catch{} wrapping the code that instantiate MyClass object.

I tried this in release mode, and can't really tell if it exits the constructor after the first throw or the last throw. Do you know if in release mode it leaves ctor since the first throw or the last? And why does it let me go to the next line when I'm in debug? shouldn't throw just exit the scope it's in?

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
   throw "exception1";
   throw "exception2";
   throw "exception3";
}

MyClass a;
```

Comment: In release mode you can add a try/catch that displays the error string on screen to see which is being thrown (if any).

Comment: `int main() { try { MyClass a;} catch(char* ex) {std::cout << ex;} return 0;}

Comment: @Mooing Duck: To catch a string literal you need a `catch(const char* ex)`. `const` is absolutely necessary. (Although MSVC++ will catch it with `catch(char* ex)`, this is an old bug in MSVC++. And no one said we are talking about MSVC++ yet :) )

Comment: @user853069 I think that's just the debugger screwing with you. It cannot be throwing one exception after another in the constructor because at the second throw the `can't have 2 active exceptions` rule will kick in and the program will be terminated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that it's a debugging issue.  An uncaught exception should, by default, kill the program.  But your debugger stops the program at the line that caused the exception, instead.  And the "continue debugging" button tells the debugger to just ignore the last fatal problem and continue going.

So the debugger continues on in the program until it reaches the second `throw`. Which would, again, be fatal.  So the debugger stops there.  Etc.

If there's a place that actually catches the thrown exception, you should see different behavior.